# Move SVG element without Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to make svg element dragable with JQuery(no UI) I have found this code
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/fDcZS/). I wanted to create something like [jsfddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/fDcZS/969/). I gues that I cant use it on svg elements like that. Any ideas how to make it ?

```
function endMove() {
    $(this).removeClass('movable');
}
function startMove() {
    $('.movable').on('mousemove', function(event) {
        var thisX = event.pageX - $(this).width() / 2,
            thisY = event.pageY - $(this).height() / 2;

        $('.movable').offset({
            left: thisX,
            top: thisY
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testedCircle").on('mousedown', function() {
        $(this).addClass('movable');
        startMove();
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('movable');
        endMove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a container for you svg tag. here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fDcZS/970/)

```
<div id="test">
 <svg width="100" height="100" id="testedCircle">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: but when you draw another circle iw will move both .. i dont want to move whole div ... just circle itself

Answer (score 0):

Just Enclose your SVG element with an outer div and use draggable functionality on that outer div instead of svg element. You have to ensure that outer div is having width in px equal to the SVG element is having. I have just added border to see the placement of outer div. Below I have placed complete Code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="containerDiv" style="width:100px;border:solid black;">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle id="testedCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function endMove() {
    $(this).removeClass('movable');
}
function startMove() {
    $('.movable').on('mousemove', function(event) {
        var thisX = event.pageX - $(this).width() / 2,
            thisY = event.pageY - $(this).height() / 2;

        $('.movable').offset({
            left: thisX,
            top: thisY
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#containerDiv").on('mousedown', function() {
        $(this).addClass('movable');
        startMove();
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('movable');
        endMove();
    });

});
```